# What is a minimal example of why it is not possible to predict call pattern of functions?

Tags: compilation, stack, cpu, execution, method-call

A stack makes it possible to execute subroutines in any order, nested subroutines and recursive subroutines, and to jump to and back from the subroutines, and to call functions with arbitrary arguments. This is important because it is impossible to predict the call pattern of the functions (and therefore impossible to print out all uses of subroutines explicitly in the instruction sequence), [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/156040/is-the-reason-for-a-stack-to-decrease-the-size-of-a-program-by-adding-the-use-o/156050#156050) says.

What is a minimal example of a program that shows that this (call pattern of functions) cannot be known beforehand?

Comment: Recursive tree traversal would be a case of what Yves is talking about.  The recursion depth depends on the tree data in memory, not available at compile time to allocate a large enough stack before the program starts running.

Comment: That seems like the pattern would still be known at compile time. If the compiled program includes the maximum depth, and then just uses what it needs. It would use a huge amount of memory for program but still seems like it is predictable. And that was my original question, "is the reason for stack to avoid wasting memory by shrinking program length", to which Yves answered "No". It would be good to understand an example of an actually unpredictable call pattern. I cannot think of one myself at the moment.

Comment: Function pointers (e.g. for virtual functions) could create an even more data-dependent call tree, where it's not just depth but which functions get called.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with that, it makes sense to me. I wrote answer that shows a minimal program with function pointers.

Comment: But I am not sure it is true that it was the case stack was originally developed. Saving program space seems like something people would think of before that. I could imagine function pointers being conceptualized later because it was discovered to be possible with stack that was already existing. But that is not what I asked about here, so I thank you for your answer a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Peter Cordes comment mentions functions pointers and I agree that is a good example. I also disagree with that the answer in the linked question, recursion, is true (the call pattern is predictable, just not how much of the call pattern will be executed), so it was good that I asked and got a clarified answer that I can agree with.

I came up with a minimal example as a program (as question states, "what is a minimal example of a program") that shows clearly how function pointers make it impossible to predict call pattern.

It has 10 functions, all called using a function pointer.

It then requests the function pointer value from the user (so that it could not be known at compile time), and executes the function. It then loops, and does it again, and again, and again.

The possible combinations of call pattern for the functions is 10^n I think, where n is number of times the loop is run. It becomes a billion if you run the loop 9 times.

That is a pretty good minimal example, that shows it with probability theory.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void a() {}
void b() {}
void c() {}
void d() {}
void e() {}
void f() {}
void g() {}
void h() {}
void i() {}
void j() {}

int main(void) 
{

    void (*foo)(); //to store memory address
    while (true) {
        printf("Now, read/input the  memory address: ");
        scanf ("%p", &foo);
        foo();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250390/discussion-on-answer-by-bipedaljoe-what-is-a-minimal-example-of-why-it-is-not-po).